# How can I reduce this long list of if statements?

Tags: java

So here I have this long line of if statements, that are supposed to detect if the value of `int[] anArray;` is within a certain range. `anArray = new int[15];` The values of `int[] anArray;`, starting from `anArray[0]` are:
49 50 51 59 0 5 9 10 15 19 50 55 89 99 100

This is the part of the code that determines if the given values are within a range:

```
int[] counterarray = new int[10];
    for (x = 14; x >= 0; x--)
    {
      System.out.println(anArray[x]);
      if (anArray[x] >= 0 && anArray[x] < 10)
      {
        counterarray[0] = counterarray[0] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 10 && anArray[x] < 20)
      {
        counterarray[1] = counterarray[1] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 20 && anArray[x] < 30)
      {
        counterarray[2] = counterarray[2] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 30 && anArray[x] < 40)
      {
        counterarray[3] = counterarray[3] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 40 && anArray[x] < 50)
      {
        counterarray[4] = counterarray[4] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 50 && anArray[x] < 60)
      {
        counterarray[5] = counterarray[5] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 60 && anArray[x] < 70)
      {
        counterarray[6] = counterarray[6] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 70 && anArray[x] < 80)
      {
        counterarray[7] = counterarray[7] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 80 && anArray[x] < 90)
      {
        counterarray[8] = counterarray[8] + 1;

      }
      if (anArray[x] >= 90 && anArray[x] < 101)
      {
        counterarray[9] = counterarray[9] + 1;

      }
    }
    System.out.println("counterarray[0] is " +counterarray[0]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[1] is " +counterarray[1]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[2] is " +counterarray[2]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[3] is " +counterarray[3]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[4] is " +counterarray[4]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[5] is " +counterarray[5]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[6] is " +counterarray[6]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[7] is " +counterarray[7]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[8] is " +counterarray[8]);
    System.out.println("counterarray[9] is " +counterarray[9]);
```

Yeah so that's the code, but that long list of if statements seems a bit redundant. The for loop flips through each of the array values and determines what range they belong in. Then the `int[] counterarray` adds up the amount of values together. So how do I make that long list of if statements more aesthetically pleasing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
int[] counterarray = new int[10];
for (x = 14; x >= 0; x--)
{
  if (anArray[x] >= 0 && anArray[x] < 101) {
    int idx = Math.min(anArray[x] / 10, 9);
    ++counterarray[idx];
  }
}
```

If all the ranges were multiples of 10 (e.g. 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, etc), then we could just do a simple divide by 10 to get the index into `counterarray`.  The `Math.min` part is to handle the odd last case which has the (original) range of 90-100; in the case of 100, idx would be equal to 10, but the `Math.min` clamps it so that it won't be an out-of-bounds index into the array.

The `if` check is to make sure we only look at values within the range that we expect (in this case 0-100).  Otherwise we might erroneously increment the last bucket for large values (e.g. 200).

Comment: Hey that actually works! But remember, in my last if statement the maximum range parameter is 101, not 100. It is not 10 more, but 11 more.

Comment: I'd +1 this if it came with some explanation -- not just _why_ it works, but how you got to it. I'm personally not a big fan of dumping code without comment. It's the old "give a person a fish, or teach them how to fish." (Then again, you're already getting plenty of upvotes without mine, so... up to you :) )

Comment: I agree with what yshavit said. I tested the code, and it worked, but it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I think the division is pretty obvious... the `Math.min` part is to handle the odd last case which has the (original) range of 90-100; in the case of 100, `idx` would be equal to `10`, but the `Math.min` clamps it so that it won't be an out-of-bounds index into the array.

Comment: Not quite equivalent: you should only increment the value if anArray[x] is in the range 0 to 100 inclusive. The min means that you'd set a value for, say, 200.

Comment: now I can agree with your post ;) You should put the explanation of the code in the answer (not only in the comments) then it would be perfect ;)

Comment: @Buddy What you consider obvious, someone else may not; that's exactly why I prefer more than just a code dump. More importantly, a reasonable reader might think, "oh that's neat! I wonder how Buddy thought of that!" By depriving them of the answer, you lose the real essence of the overall answer. Imo of course. Going to bed now, will check back in the morning. :)

Comment: @Galaxy Feel free to accept this answer if it helped you out!